# OS: Boot-up Linux

Tags: 12.04

Bought a laptop with the OS "Boot-up Linux".  How can I install Ubuntu / which instructions should I follow?  I have installed Ubuntu on a Windows PC before but this laptop (as mentioned before) only has "Boot-up Linux"

Answer (score 0):

Write the Ubuntu installation .iso to a USB flash drive, or a CD. Insert your boot medium (CD or USB drive) to the laptop, and go to the BIOS and set the first boot device to CD, or UZB-HDD, or if there's just USB, USB. You'll boot inside a Ubuntu enviroment. Launch the Install Ubuntu icon and follow the instrucions! Good luck :)